# Junit Confusion

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I am trying to test the day class using Junit Testing. This method is the method I am struggling with.

```
 public Day previousDay() {
    int y = year;
    int m = month;
    int d = date;
    if (y == GREGORIAN_START_YEAR && m == GREGORIAN_START_MONTH
            && d == GREGORIAN_START_DAY)
        d = JULIAN_END_DAY;
    else if (d > 1)
        d--;
    else 
    {
        m--;
        if (m < JANUARY) 
        {
            m = DECEMBER;
            y--;
            if (y == 0)
                y--;
        }
        d = daysPerMonth(y, m);
    }
    return new Day(y, m, d);
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
public class DayTest extends TestCase 
 {
   /**
   * Test the constructor
   */
   public void testDay()
   {
   //calling
   Day today = new Day(2015,2,14);

   assertEquals(2015,today.getYear());

   assertEquals(2,today.getMonth());

   assertEquals(14,today.getDate());
  }

  public void testAddDays()
  {
   Day today = new Day(2015,2,14);

   int n = 5;

   Day otherDay = today.addDays(n);

   assertTrue(otherDay.daysFrom(today) ==  n);
 }

 public void testPreviousDays()
 {
   Day today = new Day(2015,2,14);

   today.previousDay();

   assertEquals(13,today.getDate());
 }

 public void testLeapYear()
 {
   Day today = new Day(2015,2,14);

   assertEquals(today.isLeapYear(2015),false);
 }
 }
```

The other tests went smoothly but this test for previousday() is giving me trouble. When I call previousDay() it doesn't seem to work at all. I am confused why when the other tests worked fine. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `assertTrue(otherDay.daysFrom(today) ==  n);` Don't use other (untested) methods to verify another method of the same class.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean:

```
today = today.previousDay()
```

Right now you're ignoring the return value of the function.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I made that mistake!